# Past tense for “rentrer”

Tags: conjugaison

I just read the following sentence

> Il rentre bient­ot.

Google translate says it means “He returned soon”.
But I do not understand how is the conjugation done. I saw the rules as given here http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/rentrer.php, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Translate is (as often!) wrong. The sentence means:

> He comes back soon. / He returns soon.

The verb *rentrer* is conjugated at the *indicatif présent*.

Comment: The French verb is indeed in the present, but in this case, I think Google translate is even more wrong than you make it out to be. IMO, the better translation would be in a different construction: "He'll be coming home soon."

Answer (score 0):

In French as in English, **the present tense may have the meaning of a near future.**

- The proximity depends on the context.

"Il rentre bientôt" suggests, a priori, minutes or hours.

"Je vais au restaurant ce soir" could be said in the morning, and of course I am not already going there.

But :
"L'armistice est signé, les soldats rentrent bientôt" suggests some weeks.